# Retrieve UserDetailsManager when using ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider

Tags: java, spring-security, active-directory

I'd like the users of my application to be able to change their password. The authentication provider in the background is an Active Directory server.

The authentication itself is working, though I'm having issue retrieving an instance of `UserDetailsManager` that would allow me to change the users password.

This is my security configuration:

```
  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder) {
    authManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());
  }

  @Bean
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(
      AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider) {
    return new ProviderManager(Collections.singletonList(authenticationProvider));
  }

  @Bean
  public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
    LOGGER.info("AD provider for domain {} on {}:{}", adDomain, adHost, adPort);
    ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider =
        new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(adDomain, "ldap://" + adHost + ":" + adPort);
    provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
    provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
    provider.setUserDetailsContextMapper(userContextMapper);

    return provider;
  }

  @Bean
  public AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler() {
    return new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler();
  }

  @Bean("adUserDetailsManager")
  public UserDetailsManager getUserDetailsManager(ContextSource contextSource) {
    return new LdapUserDetailsManager(contextSource);
  }
```

In the controller that should handle the password change I've got the following code:

```
  private final UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager;

  public AccountController(
      @Qualifier("adUserDetailsManager") UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager) {
    this.userDetailsManager = userDetailsManager;
  }

  @PostMapping("/account")
  public ModelAndView changePassword(
      ModelAndView modelAndView,
      @RequestParam(required = true) String oldPassword,
      @RequestParam(required = true) String newPassword,
      @RequestParam(required = true) String confirmation) {
    modelAndView.setViewName("account");

    if (!StringUtils.equals(newPassword, confirmation)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Passwords don't match");
    }

    userDetailsManager.changePassword(oldPassword, newPassword);

    return modelAndView;
  }
```

The application starts fine (no dependency issues), but once I run the `changePassword` method I am getting an exception that the server under localhost could not be reached:

`localhost:389 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]`

It seems that the `ContextSource` that is injected in my `getUserDetailsManager` method is a default one that points to localhost, it is not the actual LDAP connection from my Active Directory provider. I couldn't find anything on the ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider that would give me an instance of `UserDetailsManager` or at least provide me with the `ContextSource` used by the AD connection, so I could wire up my own `LdapUserDetailsManager`.

Comment: Any more details in the error?  Are you using SSL?

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb Don't be fooled by the error message - I am using a remote Active Directory server, but the errors says localhost. As I said, the actual login using Active Directory is working, it's just that the `UserDetailsManager` seems to be using a default LDAP source that is configured to use localhost instead of the LDAP connection from the Active Directory provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are providing your own `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` so context source was not configured correctly .ie if you were to use not your own, it would have been something like

```
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .ldapAuthentication()
                .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
                .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
                .contextSource()
                    .url("ldap://localhost:8389/dc=springframework,dc=org")
                    .and()
```

2. **Since you are using you own implementation** and the `contextSource` was configured correctly, you have to use something like this:

- Option 1:

```
    @Bean("adUserDetailsManager")
    public UserDetailsManager getUserDetailsManager() {
        String providerUrl = "your ldap url here";
        DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource 
                = new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(providerUrl);
        contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
        return new LdapUserDetailsManager(contextSource);
    }
```

- Option 2:

```
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ContextSource contextSource() {
        String providerUrl = "your ldap url here";
        return new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(providerUrl);
    }
    
    @Bean("adUserDetailsManager")
    public UserDetailsManager getUserDetailsManager(ContextSource contextSource) {
        return new LdapUserDetailsManager(contextSource);
    }
```

Comment: Using option 1 I had to add `contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();` before returning the bean, but otherwise it seems to have done the trick. Now he's complaining about bad credentials when changing the password, but at least I've now got the connection working. Thanks!